# can I remove imagemagick by deleting directories?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew

Inexperience and enthusiasm caused me to install many copies of imagemagick, and now I can't get rmagick gem to install.

I used macports to uninstall the imagemagick versions that it knew about.

Now, if I try brew list --unbrewed

I get a long list of imagemagick files, all in the /usr/local directory. I presume that these are ones that homebrew finds but doesn't control.

Can I simply delete these directories and associated files, and get rid of imagemagick that way? Virtually all the files are in the /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.6.4 directory, or the /usr/local/include/ directory. The rest are in the /usr/local/share directory, and I assume those are just doc files of one kind or another.

If that gets rid of the beast, what's the best way to go about reinstalling ImageMagick?

-- EDIT ––

running bundle, it stalls on

```
    def try_do(src, command, &b)
  unless have_devel?
    raise <<MSG
The complier failed to generate an executable file.
You have to install development tools first.
MSG
```

Does this mean that gcc is missing? (I just reinstalled XCode, and it has compiled stuff). Or is this a Ruby-related development tool it's looking for?

Comment: What do you mean, you "can't get rmagick gem to install"? This might have nothing to do with your "many copies" of imageMagick. What are you doing and what's the actual error?

Comment: I think it does have to do with the multiple copies, as that's the error message I was getting until I removed the macports versions. Now, I get "checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***", and I've concluded I should start from scratch. There are a number of posts around the interwebs that indicate that removing all copies of ImageMagick and reinstalling is the key in this case, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This question has also been posted to Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/397537/can-i-remove-imagemagick-by-deleting-directories

Comment: I had the same issue last year. On my linux box, I had to install libmagick9-dev which are the development files. It sounds like this could be a similar case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes delete the unbrewed imagemagick files and `brew install imagemagick`. Provided you have brew in `/usr/local` the gem should install fine.